# How can I end a job without disconnecting the remote session?

Tags: windows-server-2008, job-control

How can I end a job on a windows 2008 server that has sat idle for 30 minutes without ending the user session?  We have users that run a job then minimize the job and go on to other tasks.  Because of licensing isues, we can only have a limited number of this job running at any one time, so I need to be able to automatically monitor these copies of the job and when one has sat for 30 minutes without activity, force it to end.

Answer (score 1):

Use Task Manager to kill the job and keep your session in tact.  Make sure to pay attention to the UID column so that you know who's job your killing.

Comment: And this can be an automatic function, based on the task being inactive for a period of time?

Comment: No, I was assuming you were manually killing the processes interactively.  You _could_ code something in PS or VBS to monitor a process from a user (excluding SYSTEM of course) and if the CPU is below a threshold for more than X minutes, kill the process.